# How to vertical scale a juju service unit?

Tags: juju

Suppose I deploy a PostgreSQL charm with 3 units. When I deploy, I will use a EC2 small instance. How can I change the instance type of those units after those 3 units are already running? Is this handled automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't able to change the instance type of already running units. You can however create new units with different constraints and then destroy your smaller ones. For more information check out `juju help constraints` and `juju help deploy`.

This is very easy to do using the Juju GUI: https://jujucharms.com/juju-gui/

Juju 2.x:

The GUI is included by default in Juju 2, you can access it by running `juju gui --show-credentials` which will open up the GUI in a new browser window with your credentials outputted in the console.

Juju 1.x:

You can deploy the Juju GUI to your bootstrap node using `juju deploy juju-gui --to 0` assuming that your bootstrap node is machine 0

See also:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying
- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/reference-constraints
- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-constraints